# Ubuntu- No users in 'Root' group and current user not in sudoers file

Tags: ubuntu

I accidentally removed my only user id from 'root' group, I don't have a 'root' user account. It also is not in sudoers file. What do I do to get back root access or at least restore sudoers file to older version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reboot into single user mode, or boot to a rescue CD.

Either method will allow you to modify your `/etc/sudoers` file.